# How to create a Website for Solana tokens transfer

Tags: transactions, solana, solana-web3js

I am trying to build a website using reactjs with the following goal :

- Transfer Solana and tokens that are on the solana Blockchain

I took a look on the documentation that solana provides but it was kinda hard for me to understand anything because Blockchain and reactjs are still something new for me .
So the thing is :

- Can Anyone help me by providing some simplified steps on how to integrate the solana
  Blockchain into my website and be able to transfer some coins ?

Any help will be appreciated and thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you will need:

1. A solana client library(you will need this to make rpc calls), hopefully one exists
2. A way to enable user to interact with your website through a browser extension like metamask. That provides wallet for your users

That's how most Web3 currently works. A client library on that enables to taking to the blockchain on the browser with User wallets integration(provided in the form of a browser extension)

If you need further help,feel free to checkout my github https://github.com/naftalimurgor an email: nmurgor10[at]gmail.com is in order too.
Thank you!